# Add a default constraint to an existing field with values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add a default constraint to an existing field in SQL Server using the following T-SQL:

> alter table Extra add constraint DF_Extra_ExternalRef DEFAULT ('*') for
>   ExternalRef with values

This adds the default constraint but fails to update existing records with null values.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only ever seen `WITH VALUES` used this way when adding a new column (and this is [all that is documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)). If you're adding a constraint to an existing column, I think `WITH VALUES` is a no-op. Therefore:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Extra ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Extra_ExternalRef 
  DEFAULT ('*') FOR ExternalRef;

UPDATE dbo.Extra SET ExternalRef = '*' WHERE ExternalRef IS NULL;
```