# Problem with default constraint "with values" in sql server

Tags: sql-server, default-constraint

I came to know that in Sql Server we have `WITH VALUES` that sets data inside `NULL` columns with specified values inside default constraint.
But my query is not setting values in column that have already `NULL` in it,even when i used `WITH VALUES`,
Please correct the query if I am wrong.
my query is

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DefaultTest]
(
    [id] [int] NULL
) 
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DefaultTest]
SELECT NULL
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DefaultTest] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [con_Test]  DEFAULT 1 FOR [id]
WITH VALUES
GO
SELECT * FROM [DefaultTest]
GO
DROP TABLE [DefaultTest]
```

Upon executing the query i noticed that still the column contains only NULL instead of 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a default constraint to an existing field with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184318/add-a-default-constraint-to-an-existing-field-with-values)

Comment: ["If this is used when the related column isn't also being added then it has no effect."](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql)

Comment: `WITH VALUES` is *not* supposed to update existing values. It's only effective when adding a new column

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos,@Jeroen-Mostert for the reply,I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[WITH VALUES] is used when you adding new column and it should have some value.
If you don't adding new column by [ALTER] operator then [WITH VALUES] option will be ignored.

> If this is used when the related column isn't also being added then it has no effect.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Shapkin ,Understood